# Storing certain parts of a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

For the code below, My input's are as following:

```
score Bob 10
score Jill 20
score Han 20
highscore
best Bob
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct score_entry
{
    char name[21];
    int score;
} score_entry;


int main(void) {
    int i;
    char s[100];
    score_entry readin[30];

    while (1 == scanf("%s",(char*)s))
    {
        if (strncmp(s,"score",5)){
            //how to store string an name ?
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The string `s` after the `if` statement is "nameint" ... I want to store the name to `readin[i].name` and the `int` to `readin[i].score` ... How exactly can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This works:

```
typedef struct score_entry
{
    char name[21];
    int score;
} score_entry;

int main()
{

    int i, j;
    int input_tokens;
    int score;
    int highest_score;
    int highest_individual_score;
    char input[100];
    char name[21];
    char scoretoken[10];
    score_entry readin[30] = {{0}};

    i = 0;

    while(i < 30 && fgets(input, 100, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        input_tokens = sscanf(input, "%9s %20s %d", scoretoken, name, &score);
        if (input_tokens == 3)
        {
            if (strncmp(scoretoken, "score", 5) == 0)
            {
                strncpy(readin[i].name, name, 20);
                readin[i].score = score;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else if (input_tokens == 2)
        {
            if (strncmp(scoretoken, "best", 4) == 0)
            {
                highest_individual_score = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
                {
                    if (strncmp(readin[j].name, name, 20) == 0 && readin[j].score > highest_individual_score)
                    {
                        highest_individual_score = readin[j].score;
                    }
                }
                printf("Highest score for %s: %d\n", name, highest_individual_score);
            }
        }
        else if (input_tokens == 1)
        {
            if (strncmp(scoretoken, "highscore", 9) == 0)
            {
                highest_score = 0;
                for (j = 0; j < 30; j++)
                {
                    if (readin[j].score > highest_score)
                    {
                        highest_score = readin[j].score;
                    }
                }
                printf("Highest score: %d\n", highest_score);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry i updated the question, sometimes i will input highscore and best "randomname" ..... best highscore and score are commands.... So i won't always input 3 things ... That's why i want to avoid scanf of 3 things ... sorry for that.

Comment: @Beginnernato How will you deal with inputs of `highscore` and `best [somename]`?

Comment: @Beginnernato I have edited the code to allow for the different inputs.

Comment: basically when i input highscore i want to print the highest score so far, and when i input best [somename] ... i want to print that person's name and thier bestscore.... That's why for my array i want to store the name and correspoding score, so i can play with that accordinly ..

Comment: Sorry i realized i need to press control-d for the desired output, can i make it so it output's when i press enter ?

Comment: sorry i mean, its doing what its intended to do when i press control-d .... but i want it to do when i go to a newline ?

Comment: @Beginnernato I have updated the code in my answer. I have tested it and tt works fine. All three forms of input are handled when enough tokens are entered. Try it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: since we capped of the name to max 20 char's. When i input something like `score fredflintstonefrombedrock 20` and when i say `best fredflintstonefrombedrock` im expecting `best fredflintstonefrombe 20` ... since i capped of name at 20 .. but im getting the whole name, how come ?

Comment: @Beginnernato I don't see that on my end. I enter `best bobobbobobbobobbobobbobob` (25 character long name) and I get 
`[best] [bobobbobobbobobbobob]` (20 character long name). You can ignore the `[` `]` brackets.

Comment: It was on my end .. fixed it, now i realized if i have input greater than 20 ... there is overflow carrying toward score, disrupting with best and highscore command. Is this for you too or only me ?

Comment: Also is it possible to incorporate this readstring function in your solution ? http://ideone.com/jTq3l

Comment: @Beginnernato Yes that is expected. This implementation is not meant to be robust enough to grab valid input. It trusts the user to input values within reasonable constraints. You can raise the length restriction if you like. However, if you want something robust, you'll need to use the [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) function to parse the input one token at a time.

Comment: hmmm i see, apparently that readstring function will consider only the 20 characters if 20 is in the parameter ... That's i was wondering if it would be useful ?

Comment: @Beginnernato I don't think it'll be useful because you need to read one or more tokens. readstring will only work with one token. I suggest you consider `strtok`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to use scanf for this, then you probably want:

```
int i, num;
char szScore[10];
i=0;
while( scanf( "%s, %s,%d", szScore, s, &num) )
{
  if( !strncmp(szScore, "score", 5)
  {
    strcpy( readin[i].name, s);
    readin[i].score = num;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the word "score" ?, i dont want to store that ?

Comment: IDK, what about the word score?  My response was based on an assumption you might be having difficulty understanding dot (.) or (->) accessors.  What EXACTLY are you trying to do?

Comment: basically the word score is followed by a name(string) and an score(int) ... i input score because it's basically telling me to record the person's name and it's score in an array ... the word "score" itself has no other meaning, so i dont want to store it.

Comment: ok, updated to capture "score."  I hope you realize that there is no overflow protection in doing it like this.

Comment: sorry i updated the question, sometimes i will input highscore and best "randomname" ..... best highscore and score are commands.... So i won't always input 3 things ... That's why i want to avoid scanf of 3 things ... sorry for that.